# how to create two listners in single tomcat instance?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, gps, udp

can any one explain how to create two listeners like TCP listner and UDP listner in single tomcat instance .In  my application Eagleye device supporting TCP and UDP so how can i create single instance..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a server for HTTP requests running over TCP protocol. You'll need to implement your own UDP handler and, quite possibly, your own server.

A good starting point would be investigating into network servers implementation, like [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) or my favorite [Netty](http://netty.io/). BTW, the latter can be easily embedded into JBoss. That's how I'm running my *UDP listener*.